# How to use SQLite from Cpp Library in android?

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an android project where the core is written in CPP (Let's say project-name: Testcpp). the Testcpp project uses SQLiteCpp, but after linking my cpp project to android, gradle builds all the dependent libraries of Testcpp. But when I run my application I am getting error **Disk I/O Failed** Exception. I have set the PRAGMA **journal_mode=OFF, synchronous=OFF and auto vacuum=2**. But everytime when I tried to insert the bulk data, the app is crashing. 
Any suggestions how to tackle this error.

Comment: Double check the path especially the Android permissions.

Comment: android create the database file inside data/databases directory and I am passing that path to use that database file.